# What is the derivative of $\int_0^x$ $e^{-t^{2}/a}dt$ with respect to x?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

$\int_0^x$ $e^{-t^{2}/a}dt$ 
When we encounter this kind of integrals with upper bound equal to x, how do we differentiate them with respect to x? What is the formal procedure and What is actually happening behind the scene? What are the derivative of these integral with respect to x by definition?

Comment: I assume you meant to write $dx$ in the title, rather than having the whole integral multiplied by an extra factor of $x$?

Comment: I think we need $dt$ in the integral, not $x$, not $dx$, but rather $dt$.

Comment: Review the fundamental theorem of integral calculus

Comment: I am sorry, I made a typo. I forgot to put dt and instead, I put a x unconciously.

Answer (score 1):

For the fundamental theorem of calculus $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t)dt=h\left(g(x)\right)g'(x)-h\left(f(x)\right)f'(x)$$

In this case $h_a(t)=e^\frac{-t^2}{a}$. So

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^xe^{-t^{2}/a}dt=f_a(t)=e^{\frac{-x^2}{a}}\frac{d}{dx}(x)-e^0\frac{d}{dx}(0)=e^\frac{-x^2}{a}$$